# How can I push the Lat/Long that Google Maps Geocoded into an array? Won't work.

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, geocode

I'm trying to run through a loop in Wordpress and for each item in the loop I need to geocode the address, then add the LatLng into an array. I think I have it coded right but it will not work. Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var locs = []
  function initialize() {

var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var address = "<?php echo $arrayAddress; ?>";
geo.geocode({'address':address},function(results, status){
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {              
    var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
    locs.push(myLatLng);
} else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
}
});
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I've verified that the myLatLng variable does contain the lat and long like it should. I just can't get it to push it into the variable. Is this some simple syntax I've missed?

Comment: What do you mean "can't get it to push"? Are you hitting that error condition? Did you forget to include the code that actually references the `locs` array?

Comment: Is geo.geocode an asynchronous function? You may be trying to access the value pushed to locs before it has actually been pushed.

Comment: Your code should work fine but I'm afraid you reached the limit; as far as I know, you can't send more than about ten request in the row so you would need to implement a pause :)

Comment: You can see the solution in below link
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894023/google-maps-api-function-does-not-return-results-in-time?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894023/google-maps-api-function-does-not-return-results-in-time?rq=1)